# Create breadcrumbs based on node hierarchy

Tags: javascript, object, breadcrumbs

Node hierarchy is like:

```
{
       "nodes":[
          {
             "assetId":"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",
             "assetName":"IRCTC",
             "assetType":"Company"
          },
          {
             "assetId":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",
             "assetName":"Northern Railway Fleet",
             "assetType":"Fleet"
          },
          {
             "assetId":"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",
             "assetName":"Vande Bharat Express",
             "assetType":"Train"
          }
       ],
       "edges":[
          {
             "source":"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",
             "destination":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",
             "relation":"HAS"
          },
          {
             "source":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",
             "destination":"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",
             "relation": "HAS"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Basically nodes contain set of assets list and edges contain their mapping or relation. We need to traverse nodes first and say I create a function called

createBreadcrumbs("15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836");

It should check for this node ID in edges object and retrieve its parent.

```
Breadcrumb would be:

"IRCTC > Northern Railway Fleet > Vande Bharat Express"
```

Comment: *"It should check for this node ID in edges"*. So, it gets the second object in `edges`. Why doe the output have `"IRCTC"` when it is neither in `source` or `destination`? Also, what happens if the `id` is in multiple `edges` objects eg: `createBreadcrumbs("32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe")`

Comment: "It should check for this node ID in edges". So, it gets the second object in edges - "Correct" and further it retrieves node for this parent. {
             "source":"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",
             "destination":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",
             "relation":"HAS"
          }

"IRCTC" is just the name of node. It is present in Nodes object. This is needed to display the breadcrumb.. Also destination "ID" will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating intermediate objects `nodeIdToName` and `nodeIdToParentId` for easy lookup in a while loop:

```js
const hierarchy = {
  nodes: [ { assetId:"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34", assetName:"IRCTC", assetType:"Company" }, { assetId:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe", assetName:"Northern Railway Fleet", assetType:"Fleet" }, { assetId:"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836", assetName:"Vande Bharat Express", assetType:"Train" } ],
  edges: [ { source:"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34", destination:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe", relation:"HAS" }, { source:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe", destination:"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836", relation: "HAS" } ]
};

const nodeIdToName = hierarchy.nodes.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.assetId] = obj.assetName;
  return acc;
}, {});
const nodeIdToParentId = hierarchy.edges.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.destination] = obj.source;
  return acc;
}, {});

function createBreadcrumbs(id) {
  let breadcrumb = [];
  while(nodeIdToName[id]) {
    breadcrumb.push(nodeIdToName[id]);
    id = nodeIdToParentId[id];
  }
  return breadcrumb.reverse().join(' > ');
}

const breadcrumb = createBreadcrumbs("15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836");

console.log({
  nodeIdToName,
  nodeIdToParentId,
  breadcrumb
});
```

Output:

```
{
  "nodeIdToName": {
    "cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34": "IRCTC",
    "32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe": "Northern Railway Fleet",
    "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836": "Vande Bharat Express"
  },
  "nodeIdToParentId": {
    "32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe": "cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",
    "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836": "32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe"
  },
  "breadcrumb": "IRCTC > Northern Railway Fleet > Vande Bharat Express"
}
```

Note: `nodeIdToName` and `nodeIdToParentId` added in output just for illustration

Answer (score 0):

- You could create 2 `Map` objects. One maps each node's `assetId` -> `assetName`. And another Map object which maps each edge's `destination` ->  to it's `source`.
- Create a function which takes an `id`. Get the `source` and node name for the current id.
- If the `source` is not null, then recursively call the function and append the current crumb at the end. Else, return the ,current crumb

```js
const input = {nodes:[{assetId:"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",assetName:"IRCTC",assetType:"Company"},{assetId:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",assetName:"Northern Railway Fleet",assetType:"Fleet"},{assetId:"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",assetName:"Vande Bharat Express",assetType:"Train"}],edges:[{source:"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",destination:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",relation:"HAS"},{source:"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",destination:"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",relation:"HAS"}]},
      nodeMap = new Map ( input.nodes.map(o => [o.assetId, o.assetName]) ),
      edgeMap = new Map ( input.edges.map(o => [o.destination, o.source]) )

function getCrumb(id) {
  const crumb = nodeMap.get(id),
        source = edgeMap.get(id);
        
  return source 
            ? [getCrumb(source), crumb].join(' > ')
            : crumb
}

console.log( getCrumb("15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836") )
console.log( getCrumb("32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe") )
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly.. Need one more help where i need to create hierarchical structure from flat list structure. 
With same input as above, output should be:

Parent > 
            "children" : {
                          "children" : {
{
             "assetId":"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",
             "assetName":"Vande Bharat Express",
             "assetType":"Train"
          }
}
              }

Answer (score 0):

I'll present a solution that uses the same idiomatic data structure as the other answers for this problem: an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) — however, this answer focuses on using functional programming to arrive at the solution:

The first step is to produce a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of [doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) nodes from the initial input, which will give you all the relational data that you need to solve the described problem, and to derive any other kinds of relational insights from the example input that you presented:

```js
function linkAssets (graph) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (const asset of graph.nodes) {
    map.set(asset.assetId, {value: asset});
  }

  for (const edge of graph.edges) {
    if (edge.relation === "HAS") {
      const previous = map.get(edge.source);
      const next = map.get(edge.destination);

      if (previous && next) {
        previous.next = next;
        next.previous = previous;
      }
    }
  }

  return map;
}
```

Then, you can use the map of linked list objects to build your breadcrumb path:

```js
function createBreadcrumbs (
  graph,
  lastAssetId,
  {
    delimiter = " > ",
    transformFn = (asset) => asset.assetName,
  } = {},
) {
  const map = linkAssets(graph);
  const assetPath = [];
  let node = map.get(lastAssetId);

  while (node) {
    assetPath.unshift(transformFn(node.value));
    node = node.previous;
  }

  return assetPath.join(delimiter);
}
```

Using it looks like this:

```js
const result = createBreadcrumbs(input, "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836");
console.log(result); // "IRCTC > Northern Railway Fleet > Vande Bharat Express"
```

And customizing the output is possible as well:

```js
const result2 = createBreadcrumbs(input, "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836", {
  delimiter: " ➡️ ",
  transformFn: a => `${a.assetName} (${a.assetType})`,
});

console.log(result2); // "IRCTC (Company) ➡️ Northern Railway Fleet (Fleet) ➡️ Vande Bharat Express (Train)"
```

Here's a working code snippet example with the code above and your question input:

```js
"use strict";

function linkAssets (graph) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (const asset of graph.nodes) {
    map.set(asset.assetId, {value: asset});
  }

  for (const edge of graph.edges) {
    if (edge.relation === "HAS") {
      const previous = map.get(edge.source);
      const next = map.get(edge.destination);

      if (previous && next) {
        previous.next = next;
        next.previous = previous;
      }
    }
  }

  return map;
}

function createBreadcrumbs (
  graph,
  lastAssetId,
  {
    delimiter = " > ",
    transformFn = (asset) => asset.assetName,
  } = {},
) {
  const map = linkAssets(graph);
  const assetPath = [];
  let node = map.get(lastAssetId);

  while (node) {
    assetPath.unshift(transformFn(node.value));
    node = node.previous;
  }

  return assetPath.join(delimiter);
}

const input = {"nodes":[{"assetId":"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34","assetName":"IRCTC","assetType":"Company"},{"assetId":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe","assetName":"Northern Railway Fleet","assetType":"Fleet"},{"assetId":"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836","assetName":"Vande Bharat Express","assetType":"Train"}],"edges":[{"source":"cfe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34","destination":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe","relation":"HAS"},{"source":"32d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe","destination":"15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836","relation":"HAS"}]};

const result = createBreadcrumbs(input, "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836");
console.log(result);

const result2 = createBreadcrumbs(input, "15-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836", {
  delimiter: " ➡️ ",
  transformFn: a => `${a.assetName} (${a.assetType})`,
});

console.log(result2);
```

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCwAq5oF4BQUoB8oBEAwgPYC2YAhgHYgHZ6EBiANhEvTvgcgE6UBLagQDcmTKEiwESKOigBvBpRnAAkgBMAXFDjBeQgOZicKxMABylMhB16D1Y8tWpIO+OdcQxAXzES0KABRDUMIACUIFkpgARJqOUIACRgAZVFxSWgQsMSlHA0IPSEYuOo7fSMTXRIAV14AY1tdSsdq3ijS+J0ciM7Y+N9-LOlzAHF+MAALPIZqEkK4d1UAbQBdaohQop7t9aHMwIARABkTiwWIAB4ANUoWWogAPlmcADd7x507h+8GMA6bzitTgAH4dKdzpdbp9noxatRCgAzIRbarUCAAD2A4KgkIuhRhvxe+ARyNRGgOmCRCIaAwSLCEAGsPEg4FAABSGSZTZbjHkASh0AFlKGArvYjAAaPFnAnXVnAJ4vfJQBrxPRQMhixIYgDuUFF4sljhl+OhiuVHIF-hwSJIvE56uomrMshISKg3LFUwAdPNFgLFAwcNqwL7zBy3cBfdHNDKFB9fjpoz4bQwfOI7Q6nRrgFAtrkPV6eb7C0Ug6qcAJPRzy76OtF6XJ0PICCl0pWQzg1XmoACIEC6uz5GHfWFgHXthG6o0IOmez3nZqMdjEmOJ1Owr7FrFqF1qOnu9XawOhyCoAAyS9QVfALuLxdn4Fwf1Y-PyO-VR+39++5-DokAEgt+PaZou4FQJmDAdMA9QJGGviHFIABCHSUBoDS8LUZAAEZwAA8mA9IjsGBRRAIZACMAEC8LiJpODg+g0HA9q8GQTDULiUaqHySBBugLwMVSNLUHSZRquhNFoRAGFYTh+Gcgw3rTHxwATD6UoMNEeiKpoFQOIYWk4FWUCFIyVE0Y6bZQC8BDGT2zEumxHEJPIPHmAJLzRrGqhWDYDk+DoMlydheGEcRZSkQoPhaUKLSGWRvYuvmYaJIy1AsqocBcoK1TLvm0YAAoxLyCVGOsiT7NpsgBhgWpiuOSAcjpwB6RoR44HqUwCGwnJ1Q+PbFaVvoInAPVIpOTmsQ6rkcnVvpJo8AoLj2dW6pc-6Ai+1TQTgsHwVAw3AH6ABWJBCBy5mUdRtHptBBVQEIYC1B+igEHVcAEFoKwKAQcYaN9BANEiEAALQAMyUAATLhYMACwAOwQIjYO4cjACcYMQNDEAAAwY3jDSUHjGgQ-D9n-X51gQEDajhEQyBEJT0ZeEDpAUDQdCxX9ANAxD0MaFjeMAKy4QAHAj0MYxDYOUEiIsi2DuMQPDABsACMiMNGrSKgyz1M2EDFy8CdtEJOEggsHqlAgFArDsMABueGgQMOxwPNU+YmhAxrSvo2rDRS4HcvQ4j0Ng2r8PiyLEMixjDQi+LENq87SD+bTWgEHciLQChUyUPw+ZBJiA4IGnKCu1nfCCMIPhrFKBDll9P1-XAs5NEDIPg1DsMI8jqPoxAWM4-jhPE6T5OU7uJT0vzgvC2Lkvw9Lsvy4ryvsOrWs63rtON42B5Ax2BCe+39Sd1nAtC2DosS1LMtywrSsq9v2u6-rjcz-uc9Z37aOIxDivEOMNw6R2jrHeOidk6pwPv0Mox80inzWD4XQpRWICCKKMJAGlpj+Eeh0OAtQWBvSwrJaS6FMJhXwhyZ6r0ZQEH-gHIOwCg6gIjlHGOccE5JxTgQdMy4SBsF9CwEghgOSEOIfefBfZJEkOhokMhMQIAhSoQpHKDA6HAAcow-2gCWHQxAWHDhEDuHQL4Q5BQ11LK0R0AQKAgBC8kAPB-hAZTTRcpxFMcgXgAAMAAkChKC+XMBnVBHIAlBNZmgNMPjYqYCPII4RojxFyOANDdMQA)